# Javascript: Improper Neutralization of Script-Related HTML Tags in a Web Page (Basic XSS)

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, xss, owasp, veracode

I'm spending time trying to fix veracode scan flaw CWE-80 Improper Neutralization of Script-Related HTML Tags in a Web Page (Basic XSS).

What I do is an HTTP call to my backend in order to open a blob with a download file.

```
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", url, true);
    xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";
    xhr.onreadystatechange =  () => {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
            var windowUrl = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
            var blobUrl = windowUrl.createObjectURL(new Blob([xhr.response]));
            const doc = document.createElement('a');
            document.body.appendChild(doc);
            doc.href = blobUrl;
            if (filename) {
                doc.download = filename;
            }
            doc.click();
            windowUrl.revokeObjectURL(url);
        }
    }
        xhr.send();
```

veracode complains about this line

```
document.body.appendChild(doc);
```

This call to Node.appendChild() contains a cross-site scripting (XSS) flaw. The application populates the HTTP response with untrusted input, allowing an attacker to embed malicious content, such as Javascript code, which will be executed in the context of the victim's browser. XSS vulnerabilities are commonly exploited to steal or manipulate cookies, modify presentation of content, and compromise confidential information, with new attack vectors being discovered on a regular basis.

Not sure what kind of verification upon my response I need to apply.

Comment: How did you resolve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is quite a complex topic, the first line of defence should be to Sanitise the HTML before adding it to the page with a tool like this.

https://github.com/jitbit/HtmlSanitizer

Wikipedia has a great summary on different prevention techniques.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting#Preventive_measures

Their is also this Great cheatsheet on XSS prevention

https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html

Answer (score 0):

Suppose url in line:

```
xhr.open("GET", url, true);
```

can have some malicious input then that input can be reflected in its response page in line:

```
var blobUrl = windowUrl.createObjectURL(new Blob([xhr.response]));
```

SO blobUrl can be malicious based on malicious response thus:

```
doc.href = blobUrl;
```

can be the cause of error.

Apart from this you have used filename as

```
if (filename) {
            doc.download = filename;
        }
```

If you are simply getting filename from request and using it without sanitizing it this can also cause XSS.